# ARCore – Cloud Anchors with persistent Cloud Anchors

Tags: java, android, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore

I am working with AR using "*ARCore Cloud Anchors with persistent Cloud Anchors*". I am following the [provided documentation](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/arcore-cloud-anchors#0).
I am facing an issue in the Resolve part. When I press the resolve button, nothing shows up on the frame. Even though my anchor points are getting stored in the Database but resolve isn't working properly.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old great issue since 2019. Seems the resolving can be done from the another hosting device.

Comment: Tried. No Success